# How to use python typing.Annotated?

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm having a hard time understanding from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) exactly what `typing.Annotated` is good for and an even harder time finding explanations/examples outside the documentation.

Or does it "being good for something" depend entirely on what third party libraries you're using? In what (real-world) context would you use `Annotated`?

Comment: If you don't have a tool that makes use of this, and you aren't in the process of building one, I think you can safely ignore it.  The idea behind it AFAICT is that you might in theory want to annotate a variable with something other than its type (like, say, a docstring, so that some hypothetical tool can use it to auto-generate documentation or something), and using `typing.Annotation` allows you to do that but *also* annotate it with the type.

Comment: Just want to share [this real-world](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#typingannotated-fields) use for any future wanderers who stumble across this question. The example is a data-serialization library called `pydantic` that uses `Annotated` to impose additional validators.

Comment: Much like function annotations were originally designed to attach arbitrary metadata to function parameters and the function's return value (not the value returned by any specific call to the function), `Annotated` lets you attach arbitrary metadata (though still with an eye towards using that for further type checking) to the type itself in a function or variable annotation.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`Annotated` in python allows developers to declare the type of a reference and provide additional information related to it.

```
name = Annotated[str, "first letter is capital"]
```

This tells that `name` is of type `str` and that `name[0]` is a capital letter.

On its own `Annotated` does not do anything other than assigning extra information (metadata) to a reference. It is up to another code, which can be a library, framework or your own code, to interpret the metadata and make use of it.

For example, FastAPI uses `Annotated` for data validation:

```
def read_items(q: Annotated[str, Query(max_length=50)])
```

Here the parameter `q` is of type str with a maximum length of 50. This information was communicated to FastAPI (or any other underlying library) using the Annotated keyword.

Comment: it also means `q` is a query parameter (`Query`), there is more like `Body`, `Path`, `Headers`, `Cookies`, etc

Answer (score 30):

Simply, it is a way of saying that there is metadata `x` for the type `T`:

```
Annotated[T, x]
```

use of which entirely depends on the library you are using (or your code)

> Ultimately, the responsibility of how to interpret the annotations (if
> at all) is the responsibility of the tool or library encountering the
> Annotated type.

You can use it as a lazy type checking as in [strawberry](https://strawberry.rocks/docs/types/lazy), since it can be safely ignored as explained above:

> If a library (or tool) encounters a typehint Annotated[T, x] and has
> no special logic for metadata x, it should ignore it and simply treat
> the type as T.

Or you can use it for safer typing as in [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#advantages-of-annotated)

Answer (score 14):

FastAPI [0.9.5](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/release-notes/#0950) (released yesteday) adds support for dependencies and parameters using `Annotated`. Through the documentation good examples and explanations can be found of its usage, such as:

- https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/#type-hints-with-metadata-annotations
- https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#advantages-of-annotated

Answer (score 5):

In my case I am using it for Lazy Types in the strawberry GraphQL library.
It's pretty useful if you have circular dependencies between types.
Example: https://strawberry.rocks/docs/types/lazy
oc7o