# What is the difference between pydantic Field and Annotated?

Tags: python, pydantic

Those two concepts **Field** and **Annotated** seem very similar in functionality. For example, I can define the same variable in any way as:

```
temperature: float = Field(0.0, ge=0, le=1)
temperature: Annotated[confloat(ge=0, le=1),...] = 0.0
```

Is there any drawback of using only Field or Annotated?

Comment: I can do even `temperature: Annotated[float, Field(ge=0, le=1)] = 0.0` and I see no difference too

Comment: And this is the proper way (@NikolayProkopyev).
* `confloat ` is depreaced
* temperature: float = Field(0.0, ge=0, le=1) does not reflect types properly.
* Annotated `Annotated[float, Field(ge=0, le=1)]` adds metadata to real `float` object which behaves by definition as `float`

Answer (score 1):

Similar question: [How to use python typing.Annotated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898644/how-to-use-python-typing-annotated) (see comments)

Annotated it is the `typing.Annotated`. See all possibilities here https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/

But `Field` it is only `pydantic` method for field description. See pydantic doct https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/schema/#typingannotated-fields

Answer (score 1):

**Annotated** is a way to:

- attach runtime metadata to types without changing how type checkers interpret them.
- add validation and  custom serialization for the **Field**

so you can add other metadata to temperature by using Annotated

There are some other use cases for **Annotated**
[Pydantic-Annotated](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/types/#composing-types-via-annotated)